# 12 VDC to 460 VAC 3-phase

Tags: inverter, motor-controller

I'm looking to power a 460/220 VAC 13 A/6 A 3-phase motor with 12 V batteries. It's hard to find converters that do this.

I have just begun my research but I'm leaning more towards building the circuitry myself. I understand that this is a huge undertaking and very dangerous. My original plan was to buy an inverter that goes from 12 VDC to 220 AC and then get a VFD that goes from 220 VAC to 460 V 3-phase. They are out there and they aren't too expensive, however, they are usually way too low on power.

I guess I'm asking if there is equipment out there that I can buy or a schematic that I can find to build one myself?

Comment: What on earth do you plan on using for the battery for this? That's a massive motor!

Comment: You know you'll be drawing a continuous near 500A from the 12V? Doing anything with a continous 500A DC is going to be either expensive or dangerous.

Comment: Use multiple 12V batteries in series, then you have less current to manage.

Comment: Assuming you can even get a battery, or probably multiple batteries, to do this job, what is your power source for charging it? How long do you expect to run the motor on one charge? Have you planned on spending a lot of money to cover the costs of the battery, cables, battery charger, switches, protection devices, etc?

Comment: @Finbarr Putting the batteries in series means each one carries the full current. I think you meant to say put the batteries in parallel (although that is not so desirable either since there is the problem of making sure the batteries share the load).

Comment: That's almost 6kW, you'd be hard pressed to find batteries capable of supplying that. It's not just a matter of being complicated and dangerous, it is also extremely impractical

Comment: I'm trying to electrify this motor that I have with batteries and make some kind of car or buggie with it..

Comment: The weight of this contraption alone would make it difficult to drive around. I don't think you're going to get what you want from this motor

Comment: I would take a look at companies selling EV conversion kits.

Comment: Even if you do find a design that meets your power requirements, I can pretty much guarantee you'll spend way more building your own than it would cost to buy a brand new one

Comment: @Barry Batteries in series means higher voltage, so less current for the same power output.

Comment: EVs that handle that sort of power use higher-voltage batteries, to keep the current down.

Answer (score 0):

Doing step-up conversion would be extremely inefficient, and would only complicate things. You'd still need say 96V bus voltage for up-conversion, and those batteries would need to sustain 1C discharge at 100A (!). You'd need 8 batteries that can sustain that sort of a discharge.

If all you got are automotive style batteries, they are usually good for 0.1C discharge, unless you want to kill them in a few weeks - so you'd want qty 8 of 12V batteries of 1000Ah each. In practice, those would be 8 series-connected groups of 4 paralleled 250Ah batteries. That's 2.4 metric tons of batteries, for a total cost of 15kUSD just for the batteries.

For AGM batteries, then 0.5C discharge would be OK for proof of concept, and you'd need qty 8 of 12 AGM batteries with a 24hr discharge capacity of 250Ah. Those would just barely sustain 100A discharge. That's about 800kg of batteries... I would not run them much past 50A or 5hr (1/5C) discharge.

So, 96V is an absurdly low voltage for this application - and the step-up inverter would weigh quite a bit as well - depending on how high-tech you were able to make it.

Practically speaking, you'd need about 300V DC bus voltage. The batteries will have to handle about 30A current at full throttle. For 0.5C discharge, you'd need 100Ah rated batteries, give-or-take. Those weigh about 26.5kg each. Since you'd need 25 of them, that's about 700kg. And if you drove a lot at full throttle, those wouldn't last very long either. So probably 150Ah would be a practical minimum. Those weigh about 42kg each, and you'd need about 1 metric ton of them.

You'll also need an active BMS, because neither 8 nor 25 batteries in series will last long unless they are balanced during both charge and discharge.

Of course you shouldn't be using lead-acid batteries for this, but they do have one advantage over lithium: they'll work reasonably without external heating even when they're very cold in winter. With lithium, you'll get quite a bit more energy in a metric ton of batteries :)

Answer (score 0):

It is just not practical to consider this challenge or even try to DIY compete with Tesla cars or even gocart using a 3 phase industrial motor with 7 Hp.

The starting power could be even 8x the rated power for full accleration, so you'd need a VFD with a useable interface and battery density might give you a very short runtime with your weight in Lithium batteries.

But considering the $ per cc of used motorcycle gas engines, you'd be wiser to consider those.
But then you could go retro with a 7HP [Indian](https://www.classicdriver.com/en/bike/indian/7-hp/1918/334461) ;) [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on a project that will use SLA batteries to power a three phase induction motor for a small lawn tractor, but it will be only about 2 HP, and I only expect to run it for about an hour on a charge. I have a 1 kW 12V to 220 VAC inverter, and a 1.5 kW 24V to 220 VAC inverter. I opened them up and accessed the internal 320 VDC bus links, and I have two 12V 12 A-h SLA batteries in parallel for the 12V unit, and two 12V 12 A-h batteries in series for the 24V unit. I connected the 320V DC outputs in series to get 640 VDC, which I connected to the internal DC bus link of a 440 VAC three phase inverter. I connected its output to a 1.5 HP three phase motor, and I was able to control it using the control panel.

Here is a little video clip showing this contraption in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18pCH_qxZ4k

For a tractor, the weight of lead-acid batteries is actually an advantage, and for just riding around or pulling a moderate load at only 5 MPH or so, should require only about 500 watts. These batteries comprise 576 W-h, so with great efficiency I might be able to get up an hour riding time, but realistically at least 1/2 hour. That would be about 10 amps from each battery, or about 1C, and at that rate, the Peukert Effect reduces effective A-h to about half of nominal.

You can play around with various estimates for power required for an electric vehicle based on weight, speed, acceleration (slope), and other factors, using my on-line [EV Calculator](http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm). It also has a Peukert calculator. It is written in simple HTML with JavaScript and you can even download it and use it off-line, if you wish.